# Accesing data from different collections of mongodb via springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have been trying to join two different collections of MongoDB within a Spring boot application in order to fetch the data within a single `@GetMapping` call.

These are my `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/alpha1
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@host:port/database
server.port = 4000
```

And this is what my repository looks like:

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{
    public Person findByContId(String firstName);
    public Person findByUid(String uid);
}
```

The problem is I need to make another collection regarding user feeds and its data should be fetched within the same method.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create another repository for the same like and fetch it where ever you need it**

```
@Repository
public interface UserFeedsRepository extends MongoRepository<UserFeeds, String>{
   public List<UserFeeds> findAll();
}
```